# How to retrieve the result of a function variable with arguments but no arguments?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

Here's an example of my function that I've put in my library

```
//@version=5
library("MyLibrary", overlay=true)


function2(_Arg1, _Arg2, _Arg3, _Arg4, _Arg5) =>

    Out1 = _Arg1 + _Arg2 + _Arg3 + _Arg4 + _Arg5
    Out2 = _Arg1 - _Arg2 - _Arg3 - _Arg4 - _Arg5

    [Out1, Out2]

export function1(bool _MyBool, string _MyString, line[]_LineArr, float _Arg1, float _Arg2, float _Arg3, float _Arg4, float _Arg5) =>

    [Out1, Out2] = function2(_Arg1, _Arg2, _Arg3, _Arg4, _Arg5)

    var array<line> Lines = array.new_line()
    var line newLine = na

    // calculation
    // calculation
    // calculation

    if Out1 > 0 or Out2 < 0

        // calculation
        // calculation
        // calculation

        newLine := line.new(na, na, na, na, xloc.bar_index)
        array.push(_LineArr, newLine)
        array.push(Lines,newLine)
        Lines
```

I call my function1 several times with different values like this

```
import MyPseudo/MyLibrary/1 as f
f.function1(MyBool, MyString, MyLineArr, MyArg1, MyArg2, MyArg3, MyArg4, MyArg5)
```

But in the rest of my code, I need to modify the lines. So I need to retrieve the "Lines" variable from function1.

My question is how can I retrieve the "Lines" variable without passing the arguments in the function1 call, as the different argument values are different?

I've tried this, but of course I get the error "No value assigned to the..."

```
var array<line> Lines = array.new_line()
Lines := f.funtion1()
```